# Given $a_1 \leq a_2 \leq \dots \leq a_n$, how many possible orders are there for $\{a_i + a_j\}$?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have $n$ variables $a_1 \leq a_2 \leq \dots \leq a_n$. If the values of the variables are not known, in how many ways could $\{a_i + a_j\}_{\{i,j\} \in {[n] \choose 2}}$ be ordered using $<$ and $=$?

For example, if $n=4$, we would have $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$. If we assign $a_1 = 0, a_2 = 1, a_3 = 5, a_4 = 12$, then $a_1+a_2 < a_1 + a_3 < a_2 + a_3 < a_1 + a_4 < a_2 + a_4 < a_3 + a_4$.

However, if we assign $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 4, a_3 = 5, a_4 = 6$, then $a_1 + a_2 < a_1+a_3 < a_1 + a_4 < a_2 + a_3 < a_2 + a_4 < a_3 + a_4$, which is a different ordering of $\{a_i + a_j\}$. This means that for $n=4$, we have at least two orderings of $\{a_i + a_j\}$. Of course there are many more.

For $n$ variables, how many of these orderings of $\{a_i + a_j\}$ are possible? I'd like $a_{i_1} + a_{j_1} < a_{i_2} + a_{j_2}$ to be distinct from $a_{i_1} + a_{j_1} = a_{i_2} + a_{j_2}$. Would anything preserving the natural partial ordering work?

I'd appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: So, you're not considering $a_i+a_i$, right?

Comment: No I'm not, but this is just a problem that I'm interested in theoretically, so if you have an idea that uses $a_i + a_i$, I would love to see it.

Comment: @PeterBradshaw  Then, I suggest that you use the notation $$\left\{a_i+a_j\right\}_{\{i,j\}\in \binom{[n]}{2}}$$ instead.

Comment: This looks pretty hard.

Comment: If the sums are all distinct there are only the two you show for four items.  Clearly $a_1+a_2 \lt a_1+a_3 \lt a_1+a_4 \lt a_2+a_4 \lt a_3+a_4$ so the only question is where to put $a_2+a_3$ and it can only go two places.

Comment: If the sums are all distinct, this is http://oeis.org/A231085.  Values are only given for up to $n=7$.  If you don't require that the sums be distinct it is http://oeis.org/A231074 and values are only given for up to $n=6$.  It seems to be a hard problem.